# Implementing Apollo Client for NextJS but getting Cannot read property 'WebSocket' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

Decided to switch from normal React to NextJS after watching various videos and reading articles. I'm currently trying to implement Apollo Client but am getting this (title) error and was hoping to get some help. The way my withData is currently set is

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { hasSubscription } from '@jumpn/utils-graphql';
import * as AbsintheSocket from '@absinthe/socket';
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import { createAbsintheSocketLink } from '@absinthe/socket-apollo-link';
import { Socket as PhoenixSocket } from 'phoenix';

let apolloClient = null;

const HTTP_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/graphiql';

const WS_ENDPOINT = 'ws://localhost:4000/api/v1/socket';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    url: HTTP_ENDPOINT
});

const socketLink = createAbsintheSocketLink(AbsintheSocket.create(new PhoenixSocket(WS_ENDPOINT)));

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-item');
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        }
    };
});

const link = new ApolloLink.split(
    (operation) => hasSubscription(operation.query),
    socketLink,
    authLink.concat(httpLink)
);

const create = (initialState) => {
    return new ApolloClient({
        link: link,
        cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
    });
};

const initApollo = (initialState) => {
    // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
    // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return create(initialState);
    }

    // Reuse client on the client-side
    if (!apolloClient) {
        apolloClient = create(initialState);
    }

    return apolloClient;
};

export default withApollo(initApollo);
```

All help is appreciated to understand what I did wrong and what is a better approach should there be one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because nextJs will run the code above in the server and `WebSocket` is a property that exists only in the browser, to get this fixed you can do:

```
const socketLink =
  process.browser &&
  createAbsintheSocketLink(
    AbsintheSocket.create(
      new PhoenixSocket(WS_URI)
    )
  )
```

By checking for `process.browser` you make sure that this function is executed only on client-side.